# Using COALESCE correctly in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, where-clause, coalesce

Can someone explain why coalesce doesn't work in the where clause given the following conditions below? How do we use coalesce correctly in this case without changing the below coalesce conditions and only for spoiled = Y?

Table Fruit:

```
  ITEM_NAME     ITEM_NO     SPOILED
  Apples        A15354        N 
  Bananas       BYHUG1        N
  Grapes        GR0013        Y     
  Oranges       ORULYE        N
  Guavas        GUOIUW        Y
```

Query:

```
  select fruit.item_name
  from fruit
  where fruit.item_no = coalesce('A15354','CURR_NOT_IN_TABLE','GR0013','GUOIUW')
  and fruit.spoiled = 'Y'
```

Using the query above will not return anything. Desired output should be grapes.

Desired Output:

```
  Grapes
```

Comment: what do you want to do? make your question clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here to select what you want with priorities:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT f.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DECODE(ITEM_NO, 'A15354', 1,
                                                            'CURR_NOT_IN_TABLE', 2,
                                                            'GR0013', 3,
                                                            'GUOIUW', 4, 5)) rn
    FROM fruit f
    WHERE spoiled = 'Y'
)

SELECT ITEM_NAME
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The idea here is to assign a priority from 1 to 5 for each item which is spoiled.  We use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate a sequence always starting with 1 being the highest available priority.

Answer (score 1):

While @Tim Biegeleisen gave a perfect answer on how to solve the business problem, it didn't answer the question from the OP. `COALESCE` will return the first NOT NULL value in the list of arguments. If you pass a nr of strings like you do, the value will always be the first. Usually you pass a column as argument and it will return the first NOT NULL column value

Best way to learn is to play with your query and test over and over again

```
with fruit (ITEM_NAME,ITEM_NO,SPOILED)
AS
(
SELECT 'Apples',   'A15354','N' FROM DUAL UNION 
SELECT 'Bananas',  'BYHUG1','N' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 'Grapes',   'GR0013','Y' FROM DUAL UNION     
SELECT 'Oranges',  'ORULYE','N' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 'Guavas',   'GUOIUW','Y' FROM DUAL 
)
select fruit.item_name
  from fruit
  where fruit.item_no = COALESCE('A15354','CURR_NOT_IN_TABLE','GR0013','GUOIUW')

Apples
```

That is because that `COALESCE` call only returns 'A15354'. Another way to test it is to include that statement in your SELECT, like this:

```
with fruit (ITEM_NAME,ITEM_NO,SPOILED)
AS
(
SELECT 'Apples',   'A15354','N' FROM DUAL UNION 
SELECT 'Bananas',  'BYHUG1','N' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 'Grapes',   'GR0013','Y' FROM DUAL UNION     
SELECT 'Oranges',  'ORULYE','N' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 'Guavas',   'GUOIUW','Y' FROM DUAL 
)
select 
   fruit.item_name
 , COALESCE('A15354','CURR_NOT_IN_TABLE','GR0013','GUOIUW')
  from fruit

ITEM_NA COALES
------- ------
Apples  A15354
Bananas A15354
Grapes  A15354
Guavas  A15354
Oranges A15354
```

As you see, it returns the same value for every row, simply because the first NOT NULL value is that string A15354.

`COALESCE` is not the solution for your problem, I hope this explained it a bit.