# How to use COALESCE in WHERE condition

Tags: mysql

Table A:

```
ID  Code     Modified     Created
1   Health   1462690979   1446442304
2   Freeze   null         1446442304
3   Phone    null         1446442304
4   Phone    null         1446442304
5   Health   null         1446442304
6   Hot      null         1446442304
```

I want to select table depend on the value of field modified and created:  **condition refer to modified, and if modified is null, refer to created**

Here are the query using COALESCE

```
SELECT * FROM A 
WHERE COALESCE(modified, created) = 1462690979;
```

But it always return 0 row. I thought that `COALESCE(modified, created)` will get the `modified` value if it not null else get `created` but seem like I have misunderstand the `COALESCE` function.

Can somebody explain for me about the `COALESCE` function in this case and also suggest me some way to write sql can solve the problem above? Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**: I have edit question with reproduceable value

**Update 2**: thanks to @AmitVerma comment I realize that when I code the value I selected was deleted. The above query working file.

Comment: please share the script for this

Comment: Remove the single quotes from `COALESCE('modified', 'created')`

Comment: @AmitVerma What script do you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63096336/using-coalesce-correctly-in-where-clause

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using COALESCE correctly in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63096336/using-coalesce-correctly-in-where-clause)

Comment: your query should work. I think there is no timestamp2 in Created column. Due to this you are not getting result. timestamp2 will be 'timestamp2'

Comment: Share reproduceable example (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO), not formalized 'timestamp1'.

Comment: @AmitVerma You are right, now i'm realize in my enviroment someone have delete the value i selected

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to check and need script can use below scripts

```
create table A( ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT, Code varchar(10),    Modified varchar(10),   Created varchar(10), PRIMARY KEY(ID));
insert into A(Code, Modified, Created) values('Health',   '1462690979',   '1446442304'),('Freeze',   null,         '1446442304'),('Phone',   null,         '1446442304'),('Phone',   null,         '1446442304'),('Phone1',   null,         '1462690979');

select * 
from A
WHERE COALESCE(modified, created) = '1462690979';
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this criteria,

> condition refer to modified, and if modified is null, refer to created

You can use `IFNULL` function, this query should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE IFNULL(modified, created) = timestamp2
```

The [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull) function will evaluate first argument whether it is `NULL` or not. If it is `NULL`, then take the second argument.

Comment: I will try like this but your answer not explain about the COALESCE function thought

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is to return it `SELECT` like:

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(modified, created) 
FROM A;
```

Then you'll get a result like this:

| ID | Code | Modified | Created | COALESCE(modified, created) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Health | timestamp2 | timestamp1 | timestamp2 |
| 2 | Freeze | NULL | timestamp1 | timestamp1 |
| 3 | Phone | NULL | timestamp1 | timestamp1 |
| 4 | Phone | NULL | timestamp1 | timestamp1 |
| 5 | Health | NULL | timestamp1 | timestamp1 |
| 6 | Hot | NULL | timestamp1 | timestamp1 |

So in the query above `COALESCE(modified, created)` will check `modified` column first and if it's return `NULL`, it will take `created` column and if both columns are `NULL` it will return `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. I don't realize that the value i selected had been deleted. The query in my question working fine.